# Getting a GETHDFS ERROR Admin Yield Error

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi, kerberos

[image]
I am getting this error on my GetHDFS and I don't understand why I set the 
Hadoop Configuration Resources, Kerberos Principal, Kerebros Keytab and there are files in the path I just checked via superputty and it's a valid path.

Currently the GetHDFS is just linked to a logAttribute as I am trying to get each step working before moving to the next.

Overall Process: GETHDFS -> PUTEMAIL, I am trying to print out a count of the rows of the path(csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your core-site.xml has a default filesystem that references a hostname 'gwhdpdevnnha' that is not reachable from where NiFi is running. You can trouble shoot this outside of NiFi by checking if you can run ping with that hostname from the terminal.

Comment: I ended up having the configuration for a puthdfs not gethdf for the hdfs configurations.. whoops